# Store and Increment a value by one on every new Google Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

When a customer completes a form, I want a new ticket number to be created and sent in an email.

The first error:

> "cannot read property "range" from undefined (line 9, file "Code")

and then, on lines 11, 13, and 21, I have some code to control a ticket counter to generate a unique ticket number each time the form is submitted. When I ran 2 test forms through the system, the ticket number did not populate and the counter variable did not change.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var activateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activateSheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1'));

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var row = e.range.getRowIndex(); *** line 9***

  var ticketCounter = 100; ***line 11***

  var ticketNumber = "FCB" + ticketCounter; ***line 13***

  var etrolControlsServiceEmail = "controls-service@etrol.net";

  var timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues();

  var ticketNumberLocation = sheet.getRange(row, 2);

  ticketNumberLocation.setValue(ticketNumber); ***line 21***

  var location = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValues();

  var reportedBy = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValues();

  var customerEmailAddress = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValues();

  var priority = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValues();

  var customerIssue = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValues();

  var subject =  "An issue has been reported at " + location + " " + timestamp + " " + "Ticket Number " + ticketNumber;

  var emailBody = "To: Envirotrol Controls Service Department " + "\nRE: Issue reported at " + location + "." + "\n\nAn issue has been reported  at " + location + ". Please see the details below:" + "\n\nTicket Number: " + ticketNumber + "\nLocation: " + location + "\nReported By: " + reportedBy + "\nPriority Level: " + priority + "\nIssue: " + customerIssue;

  MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmailAddress + ", " + etrolControlsServiceEmail, subject, emailBody);

  ticketCounter += 1};
```

Comment: If you are testing the code by running it from the code editor, then `e` will be `undefined`.  In order for your counter variable, `ticketCounter` to be different every time the code is run, you will need to store a value in your spreadsheet, retrieve it, increment it, then write the new value back to the spreadsheet for the next time the code runs.  Apps Script code doesn't persistently save variable values after the code completes.  You could also save the last incremented value to the Script's Properties, or to the Spreadsheet's Properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shows the strategy for storing, retrieving and incrementing the `ticketCounter` value in the Spreadsheets Document Properties.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      shFormResponses = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  ss.setActiveSheet(shFormResponses);

  var row = e.range.getRowIndex(),
      ticketCounter = PropertiesService
        .getDocumentProperties()
        .getProperty('ticketCounter');

  if (ticketCounter === undefined || ticketCounter === null) {
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('ticketCounter', '100');
    ticketCounter = '100';
  };

  var ticketNumber = "FCB" + ticketCounter,
      etrolControlsServiceEmail = "controls-service@etrol.net",
      timestamp = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 1).getValues(),
      ticketNumberLocation = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 2);

  ticketNumberLocation.setValue(ticketNumber);

  var location = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 3).getValues();
  var reportedBy = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 4).getValues();
  var customerEmailAddress = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 5).getValues();
  var priority = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 6).getValues();
  var customerIssue = shFormResponses.getRange(row, 7).getValues();
  var subject =  "An issue has been reported at " + location + " " + 
       timestamp + " " + "Ticket Number " + ticketNumber;
  var emailBody = "To: Envirotrol Controls Service Department " + 
      "\nRE: Issue reported at " + location + "." + 
      "\n\nAn issue has been reported  at " + location + 
      ". Please see the details below:" + "\n\nTicket Number: " + 
      ticketNumber + "\nLocation: " + location + "\nReported By: " + 
      reportedBy + "\nPriority Level: " + priority + "\nIssue: " + 
      customerIssue;

  MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmailAddress + ", " + etrolControlsServiceEmail, subject, emailBody);

  //Values are stored as text in the Properties Service
  var numberAsNumber = Number(ticketCounter);
  ticketCounter = (numberAsNumber + 1).toString(); 

  PropertiesService
    .getDocumentProperties()
    .setProperty('ticketCounter', ticketCounter);
};
```

Comment: This is extremely close to the functioning we require. The only issue we have now is that the ticket number keeps coming back as FCBnull. The good news is that the submissions are populating the ticket number field and sending the emails out. We just need help with the null number issue.

Comment: I added a check for null.  I changed `(ticketCounter === undefined)` to `(ticketCounter === undefined || ticketCounter === null)`.   See if it works, and comment back.  If it does work, then mark the answer as correct, and upvote it.

Comment: When I made that change, it stopped populating the ticket number field altogether. Don't you just love computers?

Comment: I added a line of code to assign a default value to the variable:  `ticketCounter = '100';`  See if that makes any difference.  Also, look in VIEW, EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT, and go to the bottom of the log, and see if the script completed, and if not, what the error msg is.  Then let me know.

Comment: We're getting closer! The number now populates but doesn't increment. I removed the extra variable assignment for ticketCounter but that made no change. error message from execution log. "[16-01-14 12:41:30:476 PST] Execution failed: ReferenceError: Function function Number() { [native code for Number.Number, arity=1] } can not be used as the left-hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator. (line 41, file "Code") [0.694 seconds total runtime]"

Comment: I changed the code to increment the number.  See change at the bottom of the code.   `var numberAsNumber = Number(ticketCounter);
 ticketCounter = (numberAsNumber + 1).toString(); `

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help!